# Routing my application properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, rails-routing

I have an application that has states. Each state has many teams. Each team has one profile, one roster, and one skill. Currently, each of these are set up as a Model (State, Team, Profile, Roster, Skill). For example:

**State Model:**

```
class State < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :teams
end
```

**Team Model:**

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :state
  has_one :profile
  has_one :roster
  has_one :skill
end
```

**Profile Model:**

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :team
end
```

...and so on.

I used the scaffold generator which uses resources :states, :teams, :profiles, :rosters, :skills for routes. I'll tell you my desired results.

1. I want to be able to go to www.example.com/states and have a list of
   states (easy - index action in my StatesController with `@states = State.all` and loop through them in the view).
2. In the states list I click on Pennsylvania. I want the resulting url to read
   www.example.com/pa and list all of the teams associated with Pennsylvania. (these are added to the database via a form and associated with a select dropdown to the state with which it belongs)
3. When I am at that url, with a list of all the Pennsylvania teams and I
   click on Eagles, I want the URL to be
   www.example.com/pa/eagles.
4. On this page, I have a nav list of the Profile, Roster and Skill
   associated to that team and when each are clicked, takes you to
   www.example.com/pa/eagles/profile, respectively, showing that view.

As you can imagine, with the scaffold, when I access www.example.com/states, I get a list of states, but when I click on Pennsylvania, and then on Eagles I get www.example.com/eagles, which in no way notifies the user which state Eagles belongs to. I want this format for description purposes since there are different states with the same team names.

What I can't wrap my head around is, is this just a matter of configuring my routes? Or is this configuration in my controllers, or both? For a problem like this, is it not beneficial to use scaffolding? Given this problem, please tell me how you would create a solution to get my desired results. If needed I can create a gist, but it really would just consist of a standard `rails g scaffold State name:string` and so on for each Model and tweaked forms to input teams, profiles, etc. into the database.

Answer (score 0):

its a matter of configuration routes and controllers. U need nested routes(resources) http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources with :path option to override how url will look like and idea of configuring controllers you can take from http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#adding-a-second-model